# How to add Google Drive to the Windows Explorer Sidebar

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer

Is there a way to add Google Drive to this sidebar not like a shortcut, but pretty much like how OneDrive is? I know there's a Google Drive link in the favorites, but is there a way to expand this like OneDrive has it expanded? Or is that only for the "OneDrive Windows Integration"?

I don't want to just add a shortcut, I want to have the same functionality. The Windows Explorer tweaking tools I've used don't do this.

[image]

Answer (score 36):

It's a pity that Google Drive haven't implemented this yet as both OneDrive and Dropbox have this configured already for Windows.

By editing and then running the .reg file below you can quickly add the Google Drive shortcut. **Ensure you edit the %USERPROFILE% value to point at your Google Drive location in the code snippet below before running, taking care to escape backslashes (i.e. `C:\\` not `C:\`).**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}]
@="Google Drive"
"System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree"=dword:00000001
"SortOrderIndex"=dword:00000042

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}\InProcServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,59,00,53,00,54,00,45,00,4D,00,52,00,4F,00,4F,00,54,00,\
25,00,5C,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6D,00,33,00,32,00,5C,00,73,00,68,\
00,65,00,6C,00,6C,00,33,00,32,00,2E,00,64,00,6C,00,6C,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}\ShellFolder]
"FolderValueFlags"=dword:00000028
"Attributes"=dword:f080004d

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}]
@="Google Drive"
"System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree"=dword:00000001
"SortOrderIndex"=dword:00000042

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}\InProcServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,59,00,53,00,54,00,45,00,4D,00,52,00,4F,00,4F,00,54,00,\
25,00,5C,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6D,00,33,00,32,00,5C,00,73,00,68,\
00,65,00,6C,00,6C,00,33,00,32,00,2E,00,64,00,6C,00,6C,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}\ShellFolder]
"FolderValueFlags"=dword:00000028
"Attributes"=dword:f080004d

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Drive\\googledrivesync.exe,0"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}\Instance]
"CLSID"="{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}\Instance\InitPropertyBag]
"Attributes"=dword:00000011
"TargetFolderPath"="%USERPROFILE%\\Google Drive"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel]
"{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}]
@="Google Drive"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Drive\\googledrivesync.exe,0"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}\Instance]
"CLSID"="{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}\Instance\InitPropertyBag]
"Attributes"=dword:00000011
"TargetFolderPath"="%USERPROFILE%\\Google Drive"
```

This content is also posted here if you're interested:
http://luke.digital/adding-google-drive-to-the-explorer-sidebar/

Comment: Thank you, silly this isn't already done during the install process. One question though, reading through it looks somewhat benign, but I wonder why the two `InProcServer32` strings were obfuscated using hex?  I converted the hex to `%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\shell32.dll`. Since this was the same string value that Dropbox used I figured it must be correct, however does it need to be entered like this? Anyway, Thanks again, this has been a big help.

Comment: I just used this to add Google Drive to my sidebar in Windows 10. The newest sync tool is now Drive File Stream so I set the %USERPROFILE% values to the "My Drive" folder. I also changed the two locations for "DefaultIcon" to point to the GoogleDriveFS.exe install location on my computer so that the icon wouldn't just be a folder.

Answer (score 8):

You could add your Google Drive folder to a new library and it would function similar to the OneDrive shortcut, albeit a couple levels down

1. Right-Click on the Google Drive Folder
2. Go to Include in library --> Create New Library

[image]

You'll now be able to see it under Libraries:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works, but it's obviously not ideal. Is this the best solution available?

Comment: Although this is a way of getting Google Drive into the sidebar, it is not on the same level as Dropbpx or OneDrive, as the OP requested. I believe that Svenkle's answer does the job properly.