# How do I add an item to the Windows 10 Explorer Sidebar

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, shortcuts, owncloud, sidebar

I occasionally use the Windows 10 explorer instead of my usual Total Commander when using windows. One thing that really bugged me was that "OneDrive" shortcut, As I don't use OneDrive.

I found the solution to removing it by editing the registry [here](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/remove-onedrive-file-explorer-sidebar-windows-10/).

That was great, however, I **DO** use *OwnCloud* and I want to add a shortcut to the Windows Explorer window where the OneDrive one used to be (preferably with the owncloud logo).

I have an Owncloud shortcut in the "Quick Access" item, which is *ok*, but I'd like better.

[image: win10 explorer screenshot]

Note: this is not for windows 8 and not for google drive so is different from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/883424/how-to-add-google-drive-to-the-windows-explorer-sidebar) question

Answer (score 6):

Note : this also works for **NextCloud**

UPDATE: here is slightly different approach for Win10 which won't conflict with google drive in case you use both - with old approach, if you go to ownCloud folder via
sidebar icon, and then right click a file and try google drive - share or whatever other option from context menu, it will stop working until you start new instance of explorer.

This approach won't give you this problem.

To cut to the chase, just create the following .bat and mind the Default Icon Path 
and of course TargetFolderPath (in this case d:\ownCloud) (Old post and solution is below this code block for your .bat

```
reg add HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79} /ve /t REG_SZ /d "Radius Cloud" /f
reg add HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79}\DefaultIcon /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\ownCloud\owncloud.exe,0" /f
reg add HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79} /v System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree /t REG_DWORD /d 0x1 /f
reg add HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79} /v SortOrderIndex /t REG_DWORD /d 0x42 /f
reg add HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79}\InProcServer32 /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %%systemroot%%\system32\shell32.dll /f
reg add HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79}\Instance /v CLSID /t REG_SZ /d {0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E} /f
reg add HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79}\Instance\InitPropertyBag /v Attributes /t REG_DWORD /d 0x11 /f
reg add HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79}\Instance\InitPropertyBag /v TargetFolderPath /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d D:\ownCloud /f
reg add HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79}\ShellFolder /v FolderValueFlags /t REG_DWORD /d 0x28 /f
reg add HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79}\ShellFolder /v Attributes /t REG_DWORD /d 0xF080004D /f
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79} /ve /t REG_SZ /d ownCloud /f
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel /v {9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79} /t REG_DWORD /d 0x1 /f
```

Here's what I did. If you need help removing it, lemme know. Tested on Win 10 Pro.
Result:
[image: ownCloud in Windows 10 explorer sidebar]

In the script below, you need to :

- Replace each occurence of CLSID with your own ([generate one online](https://www.guidgen.com/) or use guidgen.exe)
- Specify the path to your ownCloud folder (two occurences) : `"TargetFolderPath"="x:\\pathTo-ownCloudFolder"`

You can also replace the default icon by modifing this line (two occurences) :
 `@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ownCloud\\owncloud.exe,0"`

If you use NextCloud, you need to change to : `@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NextCloud\\nextcloud.exe,0"` to show the default icon.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79}]
@="ownCloud"
"System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree"=dword:00000001
"SortOrderIndex"=dword:00000042

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79}\InProcServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,59,00,53,00,54,00,45,00,4D,00,52,00,4F,00,4F,00,54,00,\
25,00,5C,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6D,00,33,00,32,00,5C,00,73,00,68,\
00,65,00,6C,00,6C,00,33,00,32,00,2E,00,64,00,6C,00,6C,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79}\ShellFolder]
"FolderValueFlags"=dword:00000028
"Attributes"=dword:f080004d

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79}]
@="ownCloud"
"System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree"=dword:00000001
"SortOrderIndex"=dword:00000042

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79}\InProcServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,59,00,53,00,54,00,45,00,4D,00,52,00,4F,00,4F,00,54,00,\
25,00,5C,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6D,00,33,00,32,00,5C,00,73,00,68,\
00,65,00,6C,00,6C,00,33,00,32,00,2E,00,64,00,6C,00,6C,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79}\ShellFolder]
"FolderValueFlags"=dword:00000028
"Attributes"=dword:f080004d

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79}\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ownCloud\\owncloud.exe,0"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79}\Instance]
"CLSID"="{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79}\Instance\InitPropertyBag]
"Attributes"=dword:00000011
"TargetFolderPath"="x:\\pathTo-ownCloudFolder"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel]
"{9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79}"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79}]
@="ownCloud"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79}\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\owncloud\\owncloud.exe,0"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79}\Instance]
"CLSID"="{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{9499128F-5BF8-4F88-989C-B5FE5F058E79}\Instance\InitPropertyBag]
"Attributes"=dword:00000011
"TargetFolderPath"="x:\\pathTo-ownCloudFolder"
```

Comment: ofcourse you can change @="ownCloud" (at 3 places) to whatever you like.

Comment: Great, this also works with NextCloud :-)

Comment: Another note. The new method works only with Win10